# Getting an element in an array in Google script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I've a lot of trouble with this sample of code here... I'm sure it is a beginner question but I've no idea what is wrong...

I want to do some calculations with the values in the array I got from a range but I cannot get the elements of the array, only the complete array...

```
var myarray = sh.getRange("A3:L3").getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < my myarray.length; i++){
  var test = myarray[0];
  myarray[i] = myarray[i] + 10;
}
```

First, is it possible to do the second line in the for loop (myarray[i] = myarray[i] + 10) ? I want to replace the value by this value plus 10.

I tried and it does not work for me and returns me NaN.

So I made the var "test" which returns me the full array and not just the first value of the array...

I am stuck and I've no idea what is wrong here...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If `test` is referring the complete array, then try using `for` loop to iterate through it.

Comment: Well I'll be in the same situation, won't I?
I try to do that with myarray but every time I put myarray[0] or myarray[i] then I have the complete array...

Answer (score 3):

The range you are reading has only one row but it still returns a 2D array, ie an array of arrays.
`myarray[0]` is the first (and only in this case) array and you should iterate in this one.

You should rewrite your code like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray[0].length; i++){
  myarray[0][i] = myarray[0][i] + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an error on `for (var i = 0; i < my myarray.length; i++){`. It's very likely that instead of `my myarray.length` it should be `myarray.length`.

By the other hand, `sh.getRange("A3:L3").getValues()` returns a 2D array son instead of `myarray[i] = myarray[i] + 10` you should use something like `myarray[i][j] = myarray[i][j] + 10`